# Failed to instantiate module httpProvider.responseInterceptors

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

I get the error below when I try to use interceptor in AngularJs,Requirejs with **ui-router**. If i use with **$routeProvider** (ngRoute), work's perfect.

What's wrong with the code?

Thank you.

**Failed to instantiate module devWeb due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at ResponseInterceptor**

Code make interception.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  define(
    function ()  {

        var ResponseInterceptor = function ( $httpProvider ) {
            var globalResponseInterceptor = function ( promise ) {

                    var onSuccess = function ( packet ) {

                        if( angular.isString(packet.data) ) {
                            return packet;
                        }
                        return packet;
                    };
                    var onFault = function (fault) {

                        var error = angular.isDefined( fault.error ) ? fault.error :

                            angular.isDefined( fault.status ) ? {
                                code: fault.status,
                                message: "Unexpected Server Error"
                            } : {
                                code: "404",
                                message: "Not Found"
                            };
                        return $$q.reject( error) ;
                    };
                    return promise.then( onSuccess, onFault );
            };
            var registerInterceptor = function ( sessao, $rootScope ,$q ) {
                    $$q         = $q;
                    $scope      = $rootScope;
                    errorModel  = sessao.error;

                    return globalResponseInterceptor;
            };

            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push( [ "sessao", "$rootScope", "$q", registerInterceptor ] );

        };

        return [ "$httpProvider", ResponseInterceptor ];
});

}());
```

Code to instantiate.

```
define([...],
    function ( RouteManagerServico, ResponseInterceptor ) {

        var app, appName = 'devWeb';

        app = angular
                .module( appName, [ "ngCookies", "ui.router", "ngRoute",  "ngSanitize"] )

                .config( RouteManagerServico )
                .config( ResponseInterceptor )

                .run( [ "$rootScope", "$state", "$location", function( $rootScope, $state, $location ) {
                    $rootScope.$state    = $state;
                    $rootScope.$location = $location;
                }] );

        angular.bootstrap( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], [ appName ] );


        return app;
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem is version of angular 1.2 to 1.3. Before httpProvider.responseInterceptors now $httpProvider.interceptors. link docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue when migrating from angular 1.2 to 1.3, the below article was insightful on how to resolve the issue related to interceptors.

https://github.com/vkarpov15/thecodebarbarian.com/blob/master/lib/posts/20150124_angularjs_interceptors.md